# MathJax is not generating the css class "MathJax_Display" for displayMath with $$ ... $$ delimiters

Tags: mathjax

I have set the delimiters for displayMath to `\[(...\]` and `$$..$$` as follow

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
            processEscapes: true,
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when using `\[(...\]` delimiters, the equation is centered. However, when using `$$...$$` it is not but is in a new line. Using Any other delimiters is fine.
Inspecting the code I found that MathJax is not generating the css class "MathJax_Display" when using `$$...$$`.

To explain more, when I put an equation between `\[...\]`, I get something like this

\[x^2+2x+1=0\]  (This will be centered in a new line)

However when I put equation between `$$...$$`, I get something like this

$$x^2+2x+1=0$$ (This will be in anew line but not centered)

Any suggestions to be able to use `$$...$$`?

Comment: There isn't enough information to help. Please share a self contained sample. Random guess: is markdown involved?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I'm only using a php function to use backticks for code. You could find an example within latin text [here](https://math.sinwajim.com/الأسئلة/استعمال-mathjax-لكتابة-المعادلات-الرياضية-ف/)

Comment: The equation source following `And this is another example showing the output when using $$…$$` is actually MathML, not a TeX string. And the MathML code is missing `display=block` as an attribute, hence it is rendered inline. So something is converting your input to MathML along the way and that part is not working correctly. There's not much more to say without knowing what's happening server-side.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Deactivating MathJax, shows that the delimiters `$$...$$` and `$...$` are no longer working nor having any effect on the text, so there is no conflict with any markdown code. On the other side when reactivating MathJax and moving `["$$","$$"]` and all other delimiters from the above configuration code, I can see that `$$...$$`,  `\(..\)` and `\[...\]`are still working and showing math with same problem issue, however `$...$` did not. Any idea?